# How to send a UDP packet with UDP length as 0 and no data

Tags: networking

I am trying to reproduce a problem which is happening in live network.
I network whenever a packet with UDP length 0 is coming my network equipment is crashing.
So to reproduce the same scenario in my LAB i need to send a UDP packet with UDP length 0 and no data block.

How can i go about it?

Comment: Use a [raw ip socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say which language you want to use but your profile shows some Python activity, so here's how to do it in Python:

```
import socket
import time

dest_addr = '10.9.87.64'  # the destination address or hostname
dest_port = 1234          # the destination port

usock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

while True:
    usock.sendto('', (dest_addr, dest_port))
    time.sleep(10)
```

That creates a UDP endpoint named `usock` and then loops forever, sending an empty string (which produces a datagram with a zero-length payload) through that endpoint to the specified destination and then waiting for ten seconds before repeating.

Comment: In Python3, this gives a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".  Change '' to b'' or to ''.encode()

Comment: I should have added something about python2 versus python3 in my edit suggestion...